# write data into excel xls file using java

Tags: java, xls

i have data saved in a table (i already collected it from a file) and i want to write it in an Excel xls file using java

i am sharing only the main class, because it shows how i save my data in a table

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        SylkParser test = new SylkParser();
        
        Reader reader = new FileReader("file.slk"); 
          
        
        List<SylkRecord> parsed = test.parseRecords(reader);
        
        SylkSheet sheet = new SylkSheet(parsed);

        String[][] table = new String[47][8];
        // print array in rectangular form
        for (int i=1; i<47; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<8; j++) {

                String data = new String();

                if (sheet.getCell(i,j) == null) { data = ""; }

                else if (sheet.getCell(i,j).valueStr instanceof String) {data = sheet.getCell(i,j).valueStr; }

                else if (sheet.getCell(i,j).valueNumber instanceof Number) {data = sheet.getCell(i,j).valueNumber.toString();}

                table[i][j]=data;//your value
                System.out.println(table[i][j]);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what Excel functions you've tried to use so far

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a library like Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/ (see also https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) to handle writing in the custom XLS format. Writing to XLSX as XML might be possible with simple XML export, though you would have a lot of work to manually generate the proper output.